# CMIS Client: apache chemistry

Tags: apache, api, client, cmis

I am writting my CMIS Client using apache chemistry open cmis API.
I have added following  direct and their transitive dependencies as well in Karaf 
one of the bundle is not coming up .

```
 <!--  CMIS dependecny list -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
            <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-commons-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
            <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
    <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-commons-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
   </dependency>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
    <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
    <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
    <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
         <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-resolver</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-wsdl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-addr</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
    <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- cxf provided -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
    <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I checked the code , none of the places I we are referring below package but still i get below exception :

org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.cache -- Cannot be resolved

let me know if you can throw some lights on it.

Comment: As per http://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/#opencmis why not depend just on `chemistry-opencmis-client-impl` and nothing else? That should work fine

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned Karaf I assume you are developing OSGi.

Then you should use the OpenCMIS OSGi Client Wrapper:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
    <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-osgi-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

A lot of packages here also are optional like CFX. So it will resolve much easier.

Edit: And you get the SessionService via DS and can extend the Client with your own Cache, AuthenticationProvider etc via separate bundles.